# Selecting optimal bands using principal component analysis

Tags: python, image, pca

I have an image which contains 50 bands, I need to select optimal bands (around 10 bands) which gives almost same information as original image but with lesser bands. I have been performing PCA analysis. I have separated all the 50 bands and I have calculated eigenvectors and values for each band and sorted accordingly.
I am not getting how to proceed further to select the optimal bands (principal components) from this data. If I combine all the eigenvectors of all bands it becomes 3 dimensional space.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have just to select the bands whose eigenvalues have the maximum absolute value. Sort them by absolute value of eigenvalues and take the first N you want.

Comment: You should ask this question in Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) because the subject is not really programming.